# Swap image src after ajax request using jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I need to swap the image src of an img element using `jQuery`. I fetch the images using `$.getJSON()` and this is a different one every time. I've chained this swap to the `hover` of an `<li>` element using jQuery, but sometimes it will lag a bit when the image is changed or the image isn't loaded correctly on the first hover. I need a valid solution that can help me to do the trick. Here is the code:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2 text-right portfolio-thumb">
    // here I used a static img tag, but I've opted to append it everytime.
    <img class="img-fluid portfolio-nav-thumb" width="80" src="">
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 portfolio-nav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <?php if( $portfolio->have_posts() ): while( $portfolio->have_posts() ): $portfolio->the_post(); ?>
            <li class="nav-item portfolio-nav-el"><a  data-id="<?php echo get_post_thumbnail_id(); ?>" class="nav-link portfolio-nav-link" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title('<h4>', '</h4>'); ?></a></li>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$('.portfolio-nav-el').on('hover', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    // here I empty the img container div
    $('.portfolio-thumb').empty();
    var id = $(this).children('.portfolio-nav-link').attr('data-id');

    //console.log(id);
    $.getJSON('https://localhost/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/media/'+id, function(response){
        // here I'm adding the img element to the parent container div
        $('.portfolio-thumb').html('<img class="img-fluid portfolio-nav-thumb" src="'+ response.source_url +'" width="80">');
    });
});
```

A preload or a fade solution can be fine?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('hover', '.portfolio-nav-el', function() {
   //Enter your code here...
});
```

This code will work on the elements that are created after ajax

Comment: The problem isn't that the images aren't displayed, but they will be displayed with a lag or they are the worong one associated to the relative wordpress post and post name. Your code isn't correct because I don't have a problem with the element `.portfolio-nav-el` that is already present on the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

I think you answered yourself. The preload is the best solution imo. I would probably load thumbnails for all items in the list. Maybe in base64 form, store it in propriate data attribute of each item and then, on hover, use it in src of your '.portfolio-thumb' element.

Comment: I'm using wordpress, the loop will load only the post title, link and the id of the featured image, I'm then using it to load with ajax the related thumbnail. I'm using this solution because the div that is holding the image are outside fro the loop and I'm not able to pass it the single posts ids using the wordpress functions!